# Rewrite query without where clause to improve performance

Tags: sql-server

I am using this below query to update my table data

```
Update BudCustomers
 set    BudCustomers.ImportedRecord = ImportedRecord
       ,BudCustomers.VersionID = @VersionId
       ,BudCustomers.STATUSID = @StatusId
       ,BudCustomers.MajorCode = EBIC.MajorCode
FROM BudCustomers BCUST
JOIN External_Blk_Itm_Contracts EBIC ON BCUST.LegalName = EBIC.CustomerName
Where     BCUST.ImportedRecord <> @ImportedRecord
       OR BCUST.STATUSID <> @StatusId
       OR BCUST.MajorCode <> EBIC.MajorCode
```

But due to performance issue i dont want to use where clause instead i want to do those where clause things on the join itself But i doubt whether i am correct or not. please suggest for this below query compared with above one. Will that work same. I am worried about AND and OR conditions on join will it work same

```
Update BudCustomers
 set    BudCustomers.ImportedRecord = ImportedRecord
       ,BudCustomers.VersionID = @VersionId
       ,BudCustomers.STATUSID = @StatusId
       ,BudCustomers.MajorCode = EBIC.MajorCode
FROM BudCustomers BCUST
JOIN External_Blk_Itm_Contracts EBIC ON BCUST.LegalName = EBIC.CustomerName AND BCUST.ImportedRecord <> @ImportedRecord OR BCUST.STATUSID <> @StatusId OR BCUST.MajorCode <> EBIC.MajorCode
```

Comment: Mixing AND and OR without brackets is not a good idea. Rewrite JOIN to (BCUST.LegalName = EBIC.CustomerName AND BCUST.ImportedRecord <> @ImportedRecord) AND (BCUST.STATUSID <> @StatusId OR BCUST.MajorCode <> EBIC.MajorCode ). But i think it will be the same for optimizer. Check both queries with "include actual execution plan" option enabled in SSMS.

Comment: Moving nonSARGable predicates to the join is not going to help performance. You could possibly help here by changing to something like (Row > Parameter OR Row < Parameter) but if that doesn't exclude most rows you will likely still get index scans.

Comment: I have made an mistake in my query. It should be: "JOIN to (BCUST.LegalName = EBIC.CustomerName) AND (BCUST.ImportedRecord <> @ImportedRecord) OR (BCUST.STATUSID <> @StatusId OR BCUST.MajorCode <> EBIC.MajorCode ))"

Comment: doesnt work this above query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, yours second query won't give the same answer as the first.  The way to rewrite it as join-only would be

```
...
JOIN External_Blk_Itm_Contracts EBIC 
   ON BCUST.LegalName = EBIC.CustomerName 
     AND (BCUST.ImportedRecord <> @ImportedRecord
          OR BCUST.STATUSID <> @StatusId
          OR BCUST.MajorCode <> EBIC.MajorCode)
```

Or you could rewrite it as WHERE-only.  On any modern SQL server (including SQL Server), all three alternatives should be optimized to the same query plan, so your first attempt is probably fine as easiest to understand.

If you're having performance issues, I'd look at whether your indexes are appropriate for the equijoin, and for that matter whether the join is even correct... are you really using the "legal name" of a customer as primary key, not some assigned or external identifier? What if a customer changes his name? What if two separate customers happen to have exactly the same name?

Comment: CustomerName is unique in table...will not have duplicate